# the import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.gl10 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I dont know why but this is my second libgdx project and it does not work, my mainactivity file is as follows:

```
    package com.me.rarster;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;

        initialize(new rarstertech(), cfg);
    }
}
```

and my other java file looks like this

```
   package com.me.rarster;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class rarstertech implements ApplicationListener {
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture texture;
    private Sprite sprite;

    @Override
    public void create() {      
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

        sprite = new Sprite(region);
        sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.9f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth());
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
        sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

The problem is the line when it states to import the gl10 and in the main activity, cfg.useGL20 - true;

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I can not see the classes GL10 in http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably using a recent version of Libgdx, like 1.0.0 (please include the version in future).  [OpenGL 1.x support was removed from Libgdx](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3311) on March 2, 2014.

Replace the `GL10` class with `GL20` (most of it is the same) and remove the `useGL20` config flag.

Comment: this answer not working properly provide some code snippets for this

Comment: @Roadies, ask a new question with the specific problem you're having.  Please include the Libgdx version.

Answer (score 1):

The use of libgdx-0.9.9 made it work for me. You can get it here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/