# Could not find class 'com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.Android GL10

Tags: android, libgdx, logcat

I'm trying to deploy my libgdx game to Android, but I keep getting this error on my logcat "**Could not find class 'com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.Android GL10', referenced from method com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.Android Graphics.setupGL**". I'm not even using AndroidGL10 as far as I know. Anybody had that error before? How do I fix it?

Comment: Replace the GL10 class with GL20 (most of it is the same) and remove the useGL20 config flag. source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23693615/1987977

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.gl10 cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691868/the-import-com-badlogic-gdx-graphics-gl10-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: I;ve already tried this solution and it's not working much. I'm using libgdx version 1.9.6. In which jar is located com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.Android GL10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. Since I'm currently using the 1.9.6 version, I had to update my gdx-backend-android.jar. I downloaded a compatible version: gdx-backend-android-1.9.6.jar. Thanks!!